# ec2 route 53 health checks are unhealthy even though instances are running healthy

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

ec2 route 53 health checks are unhealthy even though instances are running healthy. What could be the cause?

Initially it was healthy but got changed to unhealthy...

[image]

[image]

Note: I have set security group to pass all inbound and outbound traffic

Comment: "Status check" very much != "health check".

Comment: Is VPC routing properly set up, is anyone listening on port 80 and responding with something sensible, how is your health check set up in the first place?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Route53 checks if it can reach health neck from outside of your network and if it can - it declares the endpoint as healthy - not the instance status.

From the commands below I can see that the first one is still not healthy. Second, should have healthy status now - the goal is to have port 80 open (probably running apache/nginx or another web server) or change the health check to check different service.

````
curl: (7) Failed to connect to 18.205.25.100 port 80 after 229 ms: Connection refused```

> curl -I http://18.234.126.110
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Sun, 29 May 2022 10:40:19 GMT
Server: Apache/2.4.53 ()
Upgrade: h2,h2c
Connection: Upgrade
Last-Modified: Sun, 29 May 2022 10:39:04 GMT
ETag: "33-5e02426061fdc"
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Content-Length: 51
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
````